# Converting string fields to double using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, excel

I have an Excel table converted to GIS type table. And there is few columns (text string), which I need to make double in order to join it with other table. There's blank fields, but there's nothing I can do about them.

Is there any fast method to convert text to double?

Comment: How did you convert the table and to what format?

Comment: "GIS type table" is not clear. Did you convert the Excel table to a geodatabase table after adding it? If so, you could just add a new double field to it. It will also work better than a temporary Excel table.